# How to select the right <category> in RSS? is there a list?

Tags: rss, atom-feed

i am noting that in a RSS feed you can add the  tag

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_category_item.asp

But I don't undestand one thing: is there a list with all the categories? Or can I write anything? I need a category about videogames

Answer (score 1):

> Or can I write anything?

You can write anything.

Unless you're submitting your feed to a directory, with a documented set of categories, it's essentially free text.

However, [in RSS](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-2-0#ltcategorygtSubelementOfLtitemgt):

> It has one optional attribute, domain, a string that identifies a categorization taxonomy.
>
> The value of the element is a forward-slash-separated string that identifies a hierarchic location in the indicated taxonomy.

and [in Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.2.2.2):

> The "scheme" attribute is an IRI that identifies a categorization
> scheme.

you can indicate that your term is from a specific scheme.

In practice, some [schema extensions like iTunes](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itc9267a2f12) introduce a [separate element](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcbaf351599):

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" 
...
    <itunes:category text="Sports">
      <itunes:category text="Wilderness"/>
    </itunes:category>
```

rather than suggesting use of the `scheme` attribute. The iTunes guide currently [includes](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itc9267a2f12):

```
<itunes:category text="Leisure">
  <itunes:category text="Video Games" />
</itunes:category>
```